# counting elements in source on same page

Tags: php, html

I can display the number of occurences in the html of a page, on another page by adding this to the second page:

```
 <?php
 $htmlsource = file_get_contents("http://website.com/page1.php");
 echo substr_count($htmlsource, '<test>');
 ?>
```

So if page 1 has source:

```
 <test>word1</test><test>word2</test>
```

Page 2 will have "2" as output.

Now, my problem is that I want to have "2" (so the number of occurences) not to be displayed on the second page, but on the same page as the source is searched through with php. This isn't possible with the code above because the page keeps loading, which is logical.

So is there a way to get only part of the html (not based on number of characters but eg between "start" and "finish" css). Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery solution whereby you can use the each function.. An example would be as follows.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;

    $('test').each(function(){
        counter++;
    });

    alert(counter);

});
```

jsfiddle example is here http://jsfiddle.net/pdWZP/2